# Optimizing garbage collection with jsonapi-resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, jsonapi-resources, ruby-2.4

I am currently using the jsonapi-resources gem in my Rails 5 application and I'm very happy with that. To optimize RAM consumption I wanna replace the `.all` call in my controller with the following:

```
def index
  @cars = []

  Car.find_each do |car_batch|
    @cars << car_batch
  end
  # old version => @cars = Car.all
  render json: @cars
end
```

However when doing so it seems like the filters that are provided through the gem are no longer working. So while the old version actually fitlers the result for this url:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/cars?filter[brand]=Audi
```

The new version (the one with `.find_each`) ignores those filters.

How can I apply those filters again?

Comment: I think you need to provide more informations. `Car.all` has no default filters, so where do you apply a filter? Do you use a before action?

Comment: @slowjack2k The filters get automatically applied through the jsonapiresources gem when inheriting from their `ApiResourcesController`. The rest happens internally inside them gem.

Comment: At the moment the version of this gem is '0.10.0.pre' and it lags documentation. I think you should try the recommended twitter and chat channel to get support. Or you can try grape. Maybe it fits your needs too.